# How to change the temporary folder used by WixSharp when building an MSI file?

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

I am using WixSharp v1.9.2.0 to build an MSI file, but when I call the `project.BuildMsi()` method, WixSharp creates temporary files in the `%Temp%` folder of Windows. However, my project is quite large, and soon my C drive is full, causing the MSI creation to fail.

Is there a way to change the folder that WixSharp uses for its temporary files? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wix# using standard `Path.GetTempPath` & `Path.GetTempFileName` methods to get location for temp files.

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-7.0&tabs=windows#remarks) these methods checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and returns the first path found:

1. The path specified by the `TMP` environment variable.
2. The path specified by the `TEMP` environment variable.
3. The path specified by the `USERPROFILE` environment variable.
4. The Windows directory.

So, you can change the temp folder location by changing `TMP` environment variable for the project during the build and msi authoring.

To do so you need to add the following into your wix# csproj (tested for sdk-style project)

```
<UsingTask TaskName="SetEnvironmentVariableTask"
           TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" 
           AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">

  <ParameterGroup>
    <Name ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    <Value ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value);
    ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="SampleTarget" BeforeTargets="MSIAuthoring">
  <SetEnvironmentVariableTask Name="TMP" Value="D:\temp\" />
</Target>
```

Here we can see:

- `SetEnvironmentVariableTask` [inline task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2022) which executes the C# code specified inside a `Code` node
- `SampleTarget` target which is called before wix# `MSIAuthoring` target and calls `SetEnvironmentVariableTask` to set `%tmp%` to the `D:\temp\`.

Notes:

- you need to create your new `%temp%` folder before authoring msi. You can do this manually or add appropriate code into the `Main` before any wix# actions.
- this code relies on the wix# target name `MSIAuthoring` ([source](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/6cd40a5e8e63ebdc14450f44b8a0cc564ad526e4/Source/NuGet/WixSharp/build/WixSharp.targets#L3)) which is subject to change on the wix#-side. So, you need to control this aspect on every wix# update and update your code accordingly.